# PHP + Android XML Encryption/Decryption

Tags: java, php, android, encryption

I have an app that is downloading and parsing an xml into an sql database. My problem is that the data from the xml once the app is deployed could easily be scraped and other people could use my hard earned data for their own evil purposes/apps. Basically I need to encrypt the xml using php, and then decrypt it using android. I've seen a couple of php classes that make it easy to encrypt but I'm not entirely sure what method to encrypt would be compatible with android.

**Edit after solution:**

At first I thought I had to ignore brackets for some reason and was going to iterate through all the text and spit out formatted xml lol. Much simpler than that.

```
$mcrypt = new MCrypt();
$datainxml = file_get_contents("data.xml");
$cipher = $mcrypt->encrypt($value);
echo $cipher;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code might help you. Using this you can encrypt/decrypt strings between PHP and Android.

Java Part:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MCrypt {

    private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";//Dummy iv (CHANGE IT!)
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    private String SecretKey = "0123456789abcdef";//Dummy secretKey (CHANGE IT!)

    public MCrypt()
    {
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
    {
        if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] encrypted = null;

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {           
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
    {
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] decrypted = null;

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return decrypted;
    }



    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int len = data.length;
        String str = "";
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
                str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            else
                str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
        }
        return str;
    }


    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str==null) {
            return null;
        } else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        } else {
            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }



    private static String padString(String source)
    {
      char paddingChar = ' ';
      int size = 16;
      int x = source.length() % size;
      int padLength = size - x;

      for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
      {
          source += paddingChar;
      }

      return source;
    }
}
```

PHP Part:

```
<?php 

class MCrypt
{
    private $iv = 'fedcba9876543210'; #Same as in JAVA
    private $key = '0123456789abcdef'; #Same as in JAVA


    function __construct()
    {
    }

    function encrypt($str) {

      //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);    
      $iv = $this->iv;

      $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

      mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
      $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);

      mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
      mcrypt_module_close($td);

      return bin2hex($encrypted);
    }

    function decrypt($code) {
      //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);
      $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
      $iv = $this->iv;

      $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

      mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
      $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

      mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
      mcrypt_module_close($td);

      return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
    }

    protected function hex2bin($hexdata) {
      $bindata = '';

      for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
        $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
      }

      return $bindata;
    }

}
```

Usage (Java):

```
mcrypt = new MCrypt();
/* Encrypt */
String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt") );
/* Decrypt */
String decrypted = new String( mcrypt.decrypt( encrypted ) );
```

Usage (PHP):

```
$mcrypt = new MCrypt();
#Encrypt
$encrypted = $mcrypt->encrypt("Text to encrypt");
#Decrypt
$decrypted = $mcrypt->decrypt($encrypted);
```

Comment: so then to use this I would to iterate through all the tags and values and then encrypt/decrypt them?

Comment: I answered my own question. I don't know how I didn't come across that snippet in all that searching I did 0.o. This worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @SabinJose Link in answer is dead.

Comment: @SabinJose Did you know an exact equivalent of this algorithm for c# ?

Comment: @Sabin Jose can you tell me how i can convert the above Mcrypt to cordova plugin ?

Comment: Security "Crypto" provider deprecated in Android N, https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html and it affects the given Java logic, right ?