# an encryption algorithm for android and php client-server

Tags: php, android, encryption

i have a question about this post where answer is present:

[PHP + Android XML Encryption/Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929105/php-android-xml-encryption-decryption)

is this rijndael encryption algorithm ? or an innovative one ?

if it is innovative , then how much reliable it is ?

thanks

Comment: As a general rule, never use any encryption method that isn't well known.  If you don't have a phd in math you aren't close to qualified to analyze it.  Just download an encryption library and use it, don't write anything yourself.

Comment: where can i find encryption library and tutorial to how to use them on android and php ?

Comment: @GabeSechan a PhD in Maths does not imply any knowledge of cryptography (see those PhDs in Maths who wrote Telegram protocol and failed sooo hard).

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo True, consider it a (nearly) necessary but not sufficient qualification.  If you have to come to this website to ask about encryption, you need to be using a well known library-  you aren't qualified to work on one yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's AES (Rijndael) 128 used in CBC mode -- a good choice (not the best, still good).

However, **that is not encryption at all**, because **the key is hardcoded** inside the program. I would call it *obfuscation*. In fact, you can hide the hardcoded key as much as you want, but be assured that someone with enough determination will find it.