# How can I connect to my MySQL database backend through Android without exposing it to the public?

Tags: php, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've made an app for Android that uses the Retrofit HTTP API to call PHP scripts which query a database.

App -> Retrofit Call -> PHP -> Database

The PHP and the database are both hosted on the same Amazon EC2 instance.

I would like my app to be deployable to many users, but I don't know how to keep my backend private.

In order for the app to interact with the database, it must use the PHP and since users' IP addresses will vary, I have to keep that PHP code's host's IP address public so that all users can submit/download data.

The problem is that this leaves my backend open to anyone who wants to sniff out the IP address. How can I get around this issue? Is PHP/MySQL a bad choice for Android, or have I simply chosen the wrong platforms?

Comment: You generally won't have a mobile app interact directly with a database. Instead, your application will talk to an application hosted on a server or server(s) somewhere. That application will then talk to a database. You can go direct with services like firebase, but with that you have limited control on what data is going into the database.

Comment: Are you ok with the user needing a username and password?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution will be if you create an API backend for your app that in turn talks to your app-server and database. This is the standard practice of creating mobile applications that have cloud backends

AWS API Gateway would be a perfect fit for it. This is very cheap, responsive and a secure service.

Answer (score 0):

Is encryption out of the question? You can encrypt/decrypt strings or data  between android and PHP.

Some codes that I used can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929131/7199177

Answer (score 0):

You might have created APIs using PHP
You can develop the following mechanism using the PHP to secure your APIs:

1. list out the API which should be public like login, signup so anyone can access it.
2. All other APP should be accessible after a some authentication only.
3. Your APIs should be talking to your Database server which is in a private subnet.

Other options:

1. Use API-Gateway with Lambda and your Database server:
2. To reduce the use of API-gateway you can directly write a code in lambda and use aws-sdk in your application to call lambda. In backend use your database server.